# Add detached object and skip depending objects in EF CodeFirst

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first, code-first

**Goal** is to add detached root object to database and skip adding depending child objects. I tried to call dbSetRoot.Add(root) method to attach root object to context. And set state of Child object to Unchanged to skip this object on SaveChange.

**Classes**

```
public class Root
{
    [System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Key]
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public IList<Child> Childs { get; set; }
}
public class Child
{
    [System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Key]
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public int RootID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

**Code**

```
 // Prepare data to save
        Root root = new Root()
        {
            Name = DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString()
        };
        root.Childs = new List<Child>();
        root.Childs.Add(new Child()
        {
            Name = DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString()
        });

        // Save to DB
        using (TasksDbContext dbContext = new TasksDbContext())
        {
            DbSet dbSetRoot = dbContext.Set<Root>();                
            dbSetRoot.Add(root);
            dbContext.Entry(root.Childs[0]).State = System.Data.EntityState.Unchanged;
            dbContext.SaveChanges(); // exception is here
        }
```

This code throws exception "A referential integrity constraint violation occurred: The property values that define the referential constraints are not consistent between principal and dependent objects in the relationship." on SaveChanges() method.

Answer (score 0):

You've created a `Child` using the new operator, its `ID` will be '0'.

Then you've added it to the `Root`, and told the context it's Unchanged.

So now you are trying to save a `Root` object linked to an `Child` with ID 0, but the child doesn't exist in the database so you get a referential integrity constraint violation.